# installing ndiswrapper on machine w/o internet

Tags: ndiswrapper

Running 32bit 14.04 on a old Dell desktop. The pci wifi card was destroyed so now I've got a old links usb model wusb11v4 that I'm trying to use. After much googling I've learned I need to install a package called ndiswrapper but my machine no longer has internet and I have no place to go plug into Ethernet. I do have this android phone and total commander so maybe I can dl a binary and xfer to the desktop via micro sd. I believe I have the headers to build it but I've never done that before. I have 4 directories of some headers in /usr/src.

is it possible for me to dl something to get this working? ANY advice is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I really can't afford to buy a old well-supported pci card. Happy 4th!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple (Yaay!) All you need to do is go to these pages and click the download links (I'll assume the North America mirrors are O.K. after the comment about the 4th :)):

1. [ndisgtk](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndisgtk/ndisgtk_0.8.5-1ubuntu1_i386.deb)
2. [ndiswrapper-utils](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9_1.59-2_i386.deb)
3. [ndiswrapper-common](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper-common_1.59-2_all.deb)

After this is all said and done simply:

1. Open Terminal and type `cd (INSERTDIROFSDCARDHERE)`
2. Press enter
3. Type `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. Press enter
5. Done!

Comment: Never got my wusb11 working in linux but thanks to you, I did get ndiswrapper installed. Much thanks, Grammargeek.